# Word for metallic “dust”?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, synonyms

What’s the English word for the metallic “dust”, or more precisely the tiny remains (waste) of drilling, welding, cutting through metal, and similar metal processing?

Comment: Even inside the metalworking community *swarf* isn't used. -Source, an old foundry man; Dad.

Comment: I don't think you'll find a single word that describes the metal waste from all common metalworking operations.  Metalworking has an astonishingly rich tradition of specific and unambiguous vocabulary for almost every material and action you'll encounter.

Comment: Deja Vu: I just had a conversation earlier today on whether the term "saw dust" could apply to substances other than wood. (We decided it could.)  +1 for the question.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I think you're looking for the word *[shavings](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/shaving)*.

*[Filings](https://www.google.es/search?q=definition%20filing)* would be ok, too.

Comment: iron filings, yeah exactly.

Comment: The guy who says filing at the other end of the link in this answer, sounds really happy to be saying filing.

Answer (score 30):

You could generally use [Swarf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swarf), which also works for other materials too.

Swarf generally implies relatively big pieces of waste though, "metal dust" would be acceptable if you really do end up with a very fine powder.

Additionally, when grinding something, people tend to refer to the metal that goes flying as [sparks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spark_(fire))

Comment: Great, thanks. There are even several phrases like "metal debris" mentioned in that Wiki page which will work neat. Yeah, it's not really fine powder, but I couldn't find the right word so I hoped someone would get it right.

Comment: In machine shops where I've worked swarf is only used to refer to the metal waste produced by _machining_ operations like drilling, milling, or turning.  Swarf is distinct from filings and grindings.  At best, swarf refers to a small subset of what OP describes.

Comment: I suspect (well, in New Zealand English, at least... which is where I am), "swarf" is not a commonly used term for these debris. I've never heard it used, but have certainly heard "filings" and "shavings".

Answer (score 15):

In the jewellery trade it is known as lemel or lemels.  An alteration of earlier limall, limmell, from Middle English lemaille, limail, from Middle French limaille, from Old French, from limer to file, from Latin limare. (Merriam-Webster Online)

Though in all the years of living with my father, a Silversmith, I never heard him use the word.  He simply called it filings or scrap, depending on size.  Though it was always assiduously collected.

Comment: I agree with your father's terminology. In my experience with CNC steel lathes, the tiny fragments of metal shaved off of the product are referred to as *scrap* (these pieces being as little as 1 cubic mm). When filing down something made of metal, a much finer dust is produced, so *filings* is also quite fitting for this question.

Answer (score 10):

The metalwork equivalent of sawdust is ***["swarf"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swarf)***

The OED has this as:

> Fine chips or filings of stone, metal, or other material produced by a machining operation:

Answer (score 3):

For the small pieces that come off from a machining process like drilling, milling, or turning on a lathe, these are often called [**turnings**](http://www.gerdauameristeel.com/products/rc/pdf/Turnings.pdf) if you are selling them to a scrap hauler.  The smallest "dust-sized" pieces that would come from grinding or saw-cutting are sometimes also known as **filings** or **fines**.

When I learned to program a CNC laser some years ago, I was taught to call the small waste metal pieces that indicated a less than perfect cut **dross**.  This same waste from an plasma cutter or oxygen-acetylene torch would more usually be referred to as **slag**, although I always saw little difference between the two terms.

Answer (score 2):

Well... any takers for 'Robocoke' ? Seriously, I'd have to go with 'metal dust' ... swarf seems to describe much about a gathering of coils and larger shavings left under a lathe. In a sentence, "Iron Man left his failed attempt among the metal dust and swarf."

Answer (score 0):

In chemistry and chemical processing, a single-material powder or granulated material can be referred to as a 'sponge' due to the very high surface (reaction) area.

Answer (score 0):

For residue produced from machining: I'd vote for "filings" if the residue is small and dust-like. For bigger bits of leftovers, as in those left over from lathe work, the term I've heard is "chips". (Trivia du jour: I used to work at a specialty steel maker who produced steels specifically designed to ensure good chip breakage - i.e. that didn't leave those long and potentially problematic "curls" of (sharp!) steel).

For welding or cutting residue: I've heard it referred to as "spatter".

YMMV.

Answer (score -4):

Powder? That's what I'd go for.

Comment: It wasn't really fine powder I had in mind, but I didn't really know how to express it.

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @Eamonn. Your post would be improved if it included a reference and an explanation of why it answers the question. See the [help] to learn more about how to write a strong answer.